# Is there a (convenient) way of keeping the newest files within a certain storage constraint (eg 100GB) in sync on a remote system?

Tags: sync, ftp, nas, raspberry-pi

So, here is the use case: I want to sync my most recent movies from my local NAS to an USB stick attached to a remote Raspberry Pi (running openelec and acting as media center). In detail this means:

- two locations, transfer over the internet
- both systems are always connected
- ~100gb of total space which needs to be in sync
- if the space is almost used, the **oldest** files shall be deleted
- if there is a new file on the NAS, it should be automatically synced within the next 24 hours

I am quite certain that this a known use-case and that there is no need for setting up my own bug-flooded script. Any best practices or recommendations on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Already answered: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97177/rsync-most-recent-x-gb